# Paying my brothers more

Tags: new-manager

If I own a franchise and want to hire my brothers to work for me. Is it legal to pay them more than the rest? I’m not sure if there is any law that states I can’t pay them more but if anyone can help it would be appreciated.

Comment: You're asking a law question, so you may want to throw a location tag in your question.

Comment: You will also need to worry about whether this is permitted under your franchising agreement.

Comment: Besides the fact that nepotism is not OK (and the franchise-brand owner will probably frown upon it), it is likely also a sexual discrimination lawsuit (as in unequal pay) waiting to happen.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel What does "not OK" mean? An obvious defence to a sexual discrimination lawsuit is "I pay them more because they are related to me".

Comment: @GregoryCurrie It is morally questionable and frowned upon, and in some cases it might be illegal (as a form of corruption, but IANAL). Even if a defense it isn't sexual discrimination but nepotism is sufficient to win a sexual discrimination case, you still have the legal cost of defending yourself (and possibly subsequent fallout among your employees).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Nepotism is generally not illegal in the US (for example) and generally not proof of sexual discrimination. Note that anybody can sue anybody else for whatever reason.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Morally questionable?  The majority of family businesses are ran by family members. The biggest companies on the planet are ran by family members (for example Ford). Apple, Microsoft, Facebook, Amazon, Telsa are ran by a small subset of some of the greatest engineers in our society, they primarily employ the same group of people, and only when an engineer from a younger generation comes along with such a grand idea, do they graduate into that exclusive club.  I would argue the 100 companies in the world is almost entirely built entirely on nepotism to some degree.

Comment: @Donald It is morally questionable to pay a family member more just because it is family. A lot of companies have rules to prevent such situations from occurring because of that moral ambiguity and the hit in morale of other employees. I also think - but have nothing to back that up - that thriving/successful family businesses are thriving because they manage not to do nepotism (or at least limit it).

Comment: Nepotism is fine and found in virtually all major oprganizations.  Owners hire their families.  Chick Fil A is run by the family.  No need to overthink this.

Answer (score 6):

Since you didn't bother to list your location, I'll assume you're in the US, though this should apply to most western countries.

There are no laws against nepotism in private businesses. While some would argue this is discriminatory, "not related to the owner " is not a protected class. This may lead to accusations of sexism or racism however.

As a franchisee however, you are bound by the conditions you agreed to. I would strongly suggest checking your contract and possibly asking directly.

Whether or not you can get away with this, the real question is "should you?" The answer to that is a resounding **no, you shouldn't**.

The moment anyone finds out about this it will destroy morale. As you have made it clear that pay (and presumably promotions and other incentives) are not tied to merit, employees will likely put in the bare minimum and/or leave.

This can also be unpleasant for your brothers. Once people know you employ and pay based on nepotism, it can be used as a reason for anything. It doesn't matter how good they are at the job, everyone will simply assume that they're incompetent and resent how easy they have it.

Comment: There's also the problem you could get with the tax office if they find out - they will assume that you did this to save on taxes. Why don't you just give them some cash out of your own money, that has been fully taxed? Would be completely legal, but paying them with company money is more "tax effective", which is why your tax office will be unhappy.

Comment: @gnasher729 - How does paying a family member save on taxes?  If both siblings are adults, they cannot file combined taxes, which only works for recognized partnerships (or in the case the sibling is not an adult).  I don't follow the "save on taxes" thought process. The owner of a franchise most certainly would separate business and personal taxes.